# how can I sum the values in two maps and return the value using guava

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

How can I sum the values in two maps and return the map with summed values using guava ? It can be safely assumed, both maps will have the same set of keys.

For e.g.:

```
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> filteredPrice
[ 1 : 100 ]
[ 2 : 50 ]
[ 3 : 200 ]
```

Other map

```
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> pkgPrice
[ 1 : 10 ]
[ 2 : 20 ]
[ 3 : 30 ]
```

Summed map

```
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> sumPrice
[ 1 : 110 ]
[ 2 : 70 ]
[ 3 : 230 ]
```

I know I can iterate through these maps and sum the values easily, but is there a cleaner way to do this using one of the guava methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

If you're *sure* that both maps have the same keys, I *suppose* you could do

```
Maps.transformEntries(pkgPrice,
    new EntryTransformer<OccupancyType, BigDecimal, BigDecimal>() {
  public BigDecimal transformEntry(OccupancyType key, BigDecimal pkPrice) {
    return pkPrice.add(filteredPrice.get(key));
  }
});
```

but that said, this seems to fall squarely into the category of ["the direct approach is the cleanest."](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained)  (Additionally, this implementation will recompute the values every time you request them, unless you do a copy.  Still, this is almost certainly unnecessarily complicated; the direct, imperative approach is almost certainly preferable here.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead with the `direct approach` and I'd like to mark your answer as the answer. However, by doing so, I don't want to misguide someone to think and use transformEntries(...). Any ideas on how we can do this here ?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on this: `Additionally, this implementation will recompute the values every time you request them, unless you do a copy` ? Would appreciate if you could share any reference links.

Comment: If you just set `sumPrice` to the map computed using the above method, then if you call `sumPrice.get(key)` more than once, it'll recompute the sum each time.  `Maps.transformEntries` returns a _view_, not a copy, which means that queries to the returned map read through to the backing map and get recomputed.

Answer (score 2):

With [functionaljava](http://functionaljava.org):

You could define a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) instance for map. (I am surprised [this is not already present in the library](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/Monoid.java).)

```
public static <K, V> Monoid<Map<K, V>> mapMonoid(final Monoid<V> valueMonoid) {
  return new Monoid<Map<K, V>>(

    // associative binary operation
    new F2<Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>>() {
      public Map<K, V> f(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2) {
        // logic for merging two maps
      }
    },

    // identity
    new HashMap<K, V>()
  ); 
}
```

And then use it so:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mergedMap = 
  mapMonoid(Monoid.intAdditionMonoid).sum(m1, m2);
```

This way, you can even *sum* a list of maps.

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> maps = /* list of maps */;
Map<Integer, Integer> total = 
  mapMonoid(Monoid.intAdditionMonoid).sumLeft(maps);
```