# Adding values of two maps whenever there is a key match

Tags: java, dictionary, addition

Say I have a map like

```
{one=1; two=1; three=1}
```

and another map like

```
{one=4; two=4; three=4}
```

I know that putAll() would add unique keys and replace existing keys.
Will it be possible to do an addition of both the maps which would produce a result like adding the values whenever there is an existing keyword.

```
{one=5; two=5; three=5}
```

Comment: Yes, approx. 5-6 lines of code. Have you tried anything?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223561/how-can-i-sum-the-values-in-two-maps-and-return-the-value-using-guava

Comment: Loop through one map, get value for matching key in second map, sum both values and set it back to second map. Try it and let us know the result.

Comment: Do you want to know whether there is a provided method (like `putAll`) that will do it for you? Or are you asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: Just wanted to keep the question simple. I am trying out some parallel programming where I would have 4 maps of size approximately 2/3GB each. So thought looping through them would be taxing on my processor and wanted to know if there is any available method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and override the putAll method.

```
public class MyMap extends java.util.HashMap{
 @Override
 public void putAll(java.util.Map mapToAdd){
      java.util.Iterator iterKeys = keySet().iterator();
      while(iterKeys.hasNext()){
           String currentKey = (String)iterKeys.next();
           if(mapToAdd.containsKey(currentKey)){
                mapToAdd.put(currentKey, new Integer(Integer.parseInt(get(currentKey).toString()) + Integer.parseInt(mapToAdd.get(currentKey).toString())));
           }else{
                mapToAdd.put(currentKey, get(currentKey));
           }
      }
      super.putAll(mapToAdd);
 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
     MyMap m1 = new MyMap();
     m1.put("One", new Integer(1));
     m1.put("Two", new Integer(2));
     m1.put("Three", new Integer(3));
     MyMap m2 = new MyMap();
     m2.put("One", new Integer(4));
     m2.put("Two", new Integer(5));
     m2.put("Three", new Integer(6));
     m1.putAll(m2);
     System.out.println(m1);
 }
```

}

Now, create objects of MyMap instead of HashMap.  Created a fiddle [Here](http://ideone.com/2BHYUr)

Comment: But I believe the implementation in `HashMap` might be doing additional stuffs that will get skipped with this overriden method.

Comment: For example - I just found a `resize` method getting called inside `putAll` in certain scenarios.

Comment: @NishantShreshth Updated my answer with super.putAll so that our implementation do not skip the actual HashMap implementation.

Comment: With that addition you are negating all the work you did. And you should not inherit from map since MyMap is not behaviorally a map anymore. Make a simple utility method.

Comment: @Esailija I am updating the input map and then finally putting input map elements in the current map. Have a look at the fiddle here - http://ideone.com/2BHYUr

Answer (score 0):

Create a [new `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28%29), then for [all entries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) `x` in `map1`, if `map2` [contains key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) `x`, [put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) the addition of both values into the new map with key `x`.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
             Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
             Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 1);
    map.put("three", 1);

    map1.put("one", 4);
    map1.put("two", 4);
    map1.put("three", 4);


    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(map1.get(entry.getKey())+entry.getValue());
                        map2.put(entry.getKey(),map1.get(entry.getKey())+entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Works with a generic key type. Value type remains `Integer` as we are adding them.

```
public <K> void putAndAdd(Map<K, Integer> to,
        Map<? extends K, ? extends Integer> from) {
    for (Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends Integer>> i = from
            .entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends Integer> e = i.next();
        if (to.get(e.getKey()) != null) {
            to.put(e.getKey(), to.get(e.getKey()) + e.getValue());
        } else {
            to.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```