# How to add values in a multi map

Tags: java, multimap

I can't seem to figure this out even after look at this: [Adding values of two maps whenever there is a key match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136508/adding-values-of-two-maps-whenever-there-is-a-key-match). I made a multi map that contains radius as keys and the amplitude as values. But there are duplicates of keys. So I want to traverse the whole map and if there are duplicate keys I want to add the values of those keys. I have tried adding it to a new map or a double sum but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing.

```
      Multimap<String, String> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
      for(......){
            String newRad = String.valueOf(radius);
            String val = String.valueOf(num);
            multimap.put(newRad, val);
      }
       ........
          double s=0.00;
         //java.util.Map multimap2;
         Multimap<Double, Double> multimap2 = LinkedListMultimap.create();
         Iterator it = multimap.entries().iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                double currentKey = Double.parseDouble((String) pairs.getKey());
                String newRad = String.valueOf(1.83);
                if(multimap.containsKey(newRad)){
                    double values = Double.parseDouble((String) pairs.getValue());
                    s += values;
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                else{
                    s = 0.00;
                }

                System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
                //it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }
```

So basically it should be like this:
the multimap contains:

```
1.36 = 59.0
1.36 = 65.0
1.35 = 56.0
1.35 = 71.0
1.34 = 64.0
1.34 = 75.0
1.33 = 59.0
```

Afterwards it should be like this (it should find any duplicate keys in the multimap and add the values):

```
1.36 = 124.0
1.35 = 127.0
1.34 = 139.0
1.33 = 59.0
```

***UPDATE:***
So I am being able to add the values but I thinks its adding all the value in the map not just the ones with the duplicate. I tried it on 1.83 and it gives me values like 7337061.0 and it keeps increasing. What is wrong with my if statement?

Comment: What implementation of Multimap are you using?

Comment: @user2321368 I am using Guava Multi map with linked hash map to maintain the order.

Comment: I don't think you can have duplicate keys into a Multimap. Multiple values (possibly duplicate) for a single key yes but not duplicate keys.

Comment: @Eypros in this one you can. The Guava multi map allows the user to add duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never ever use `Double`s as a key to a map, for the same reason that you should never ever compare floating point values (`float` and `double`) using `==` - different binary values may be very close to each other and have the same representation when printed or converted to `String`, but they will have a different `hashCode()` and will not match using `equals()`.

I would suggest converting to an integer or to string forms - f.e. if you need 2 decimal digit  accuracy, use `(int)(value*100)` as the key, or use a specific `NumberFormat` to convert them to Strings.

Comment: I did that now but I can't seem to fix my problem. I can't get the duplicates key and add their values together. The above code still creates many errors.

Comment: Change `double currentKey = (double) it.next();` to 
`double currentKey = pairs.getKey();`. Also, where is your addition of all the values; Have you read the [MultiMap documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)? Also, why do you need a `MultiMap` for the second `Map`?

Comment: double currentKey = pairs.getKey(); this line creates an error because pairs.getKey() returns an object and I can't convert it to a double. I was trying to add the values to the double sum but it doesn't convert the values to a double so I tried using map maybe that would help.

Comment: Okay I was able to convert the keys and values to doubles but I can't get add the values, I don't know but its not finding the duplicates and adding the values. All it prints is 0. You can see the updated code in the question.